# Plotting two lines with the same starting point

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given the coordinates of 3 points x, y, z, I would like to join x-y and x-z as 2 line segments, with the same starting point x. But the plot is displaying 2 intersecting lines, with starting and ending points other than x, y, z. I would like some help fixing this.

```
x = [0, 9]
y = [7, 2]
z = [4, 3]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you should not give individual points as `x` and `y` to `plt.plot`. Instead, you should give a list of x coordinates and a list of y coordinates. So something like `plt.plot([x[0], y[0]], [x[1], y[1]])` should give you the first line segment.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I am looking for plotting 2 line segments, the first one starting at x ending at y; the second one starting at x ending at z. plt.plot may be misleading to you but I am happy to use something other than plt.plot.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney or is it only achievable with more point inputs even if I don't use plt.plot, like tmdavison mentioned?

Comment: Maybe `xy = zip(x, y)` and `xz = zip(x, z)` then `plt.plot(*xy, *xz)`: see [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvKwd.png). This is equivalent to the way mentioned by @tmdavison. See `xy == [(0, 7), (9, 2)]` and `xz == [(0, 4), (9, 3)]`